How can fix hole in model when add Subdivision
I will try to apply the Boolean model first, and when it connects the model, I will try to add a subdivision, and then it suddenly appears with such a hole. How can I solve it? Because I am not good at using this program, I have found many methods that seem impossible to solve at all. Can someone help me?

please provide blend file because we don't know your geometry and we don't know what you added to use in your boolean modifier. thx.

This is my first time posting a question on this website. How can I upload files?

just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

@Chris    You can download my blend file here Thank you so much,  I recently started using Blender, so there may be some distortion in the sculpting. I don't know what to do. Can you show me what to do?

after you applied your boolean modifier, improve your geometry e.g. like this:

if you then add a subdiv modifier:


Note: my modelling is far from being perfect. I just wanted to show a way (or the principle) how you could add edges, to "keep" your hole when adding subdiv.

In the part where this hole was added Because I added a square, I want to create an arch from the square. I don't know a lot of methods from this program, so I just created that part. And I don't know if there's any holes left. Because this is my first project. So what should I do?
